# Show that $2 < e^{1/(n+1)} + e^{-1/n}$

Tags: inequality

I'm trying to show $2 < e^{1/(n+1)} + e^{-1/n}$.

I can show that $ 2 < e^{1/n} + e^{-1/(n+1)}$ since

$$2 \leq 2\cosh\left(\frac{1}{n}\right) = e^{1/n} + e^{-1/n} < e^{1/n} + e^{-1/(n+1)}$$

but I'm still having trouble with the other inequality. I though using $\cosh$ again might help but I can't get anywhere.

Comment: For what values of $n$?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/810602/what-alpha-such-that-e-xe-y-geq-2e-sqrt-alpha

Answer (score 2):

**Lemma.** If $xy=1$ then $e^{-x}+e^{-y} \ge \frac2e$, with equality iff $x=y=1$.

Applying this lemma with $x=\frac{n}{n+1}$ and $y=\frac{n+1}{n}$ yields
$$ e^{1/(n+1)} + e^{-1/n}
= e(e^{\frac1{n+1}-1} + e^{-\frac1n-1})
= e(e^{-n/(n+1)} + e^{-(n+1)/n})
> 2 $$
as desired.

*Proof of lemma.*  [My previous proof of this lemma was wrong; it established the convexity of $e^{-e^t}$ on $(0,\infty)$ but then invoked it for $(-\infty,\infty)$.  This proof is more technical but, I believe, correct.]

If $x<0$ then $e^{-x}+e^{-y} > e^{-x} > 1 > \tfrac2e$.  From now on, assume $x>0$.

First, $e^{-x}+e^{-1/x}$ has a global minimum on $(0,\infty)$; here is a standard argument.  Let $b>0$ be such that $e^{-x}+e^{-1/x}>\frac12(1+\frac2e)$ whenever $x>b$; such $b$ exists because $e^{-x}+e^{-1/x}\to 1 > \frac12(1+\frac2e)$ as $x\to\infty$.  Similarly, let $a>0$ be such that $e^{-x}+e^{-1/x}>\frac12(1+\frac2e)$ whenever $0<x<a$.  By continuity and compactness, $e^{-x}+e^{-1/x}$ attains a minimum $M$ for $x\in[a,b]$.  Since $e^{-1}+e^{-1/1} = \frac2e < \frac12(1+\frac2e)$, we know that $1\in[a,b]$; thus also $M\le\frac2e<\frac12(1+\frac2e)$.  Since $e^{-x}+e^{-1/x} > \frac12(1+\frac2e)$ for all $x\notin[a,b]$, it follows that $M$ is a global minimum.

Equivalently, $e^{-x}+e^{-y}$ has a global minimum on the curve $xy=1$, $x>0$.  I will show that $e^{-x}+e^{-y}$ has only one critical point on this curve, namely $x=y=1$; it follows that this is the global minimum, as desired.

To find the critical points, we use Lagrange multipliers, which give the system
$$ \left\{\begin{aligned}
xy &= 1 \\
\lambda x &= e^{-y} \\
\lambda y &= e^{-x}
\end{aligned}\right. $$
Thus $\lambda^2 = \lambda^2 xy = e^{-x-y}$, and so $e^{-2y} = \lambda^2 x^2 = x^2 e^{-x-y}$, which since $x>0$ yields
$$ x = e^{(x-y)/2} $$
Since $xy=1$, we also have
$$ y = e^{(y-x)/2} $$
If $x\ne y$, then by the inequality of the geometric and logarithmic means,
$$ 1 = \sqrt{xy} < \frac{x-y}{\log x - \log y}
= \frac{x-y}{\frac{x-y}2 - \frac{y-x}2} = 1 $$
which is absurd.  Thus any critical point must satisfy $x=y$, as claimed.

Comment: (Edited, completely replacing the broken proof of the lemma.)

Comment: Is $e^{-e^x}$ a Convex function? If $x,y\gt0$, Let $x=e^u,y=e^v$, then $e^{-x}+ e^{-y}\geq 2e^{-\sqrt{xy}}$?

Comment: $e^{-e^x}$ is convex on $[0,\infty)$, so that argument works if $u,v\ge 0$, i.e., $x,y\ge 1$.  But in our application, one of them is less than 1.  @Clin

Comment: (That's what was wrong with my previous proof.)

Comment: $x\gt0, e^x\gt 1+x+\frac{x^2}2$. It is easy to check $$e^{1-x}+e^{1-y}-2\gt (1-x)+\frac{(1-x)^2}2 +(1-y)+\frac{(1-y)^2}2 =(..)^4 $$

Comment: $=\dfrac12 (\sqrt x-\sqrt y)^4$,

Comment: Assuming $x<1$ and $y<1$?  We have $x<1$ and $y>1$.

Comment: oh, my mistake. oos...

Comment: I guess 2016's method work

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/810602/what-alpha-such-that-e-xe-y-geq-2e-sqrt-alpha

Answer (score 1):

well, since

$$ \left(\frac1{4! n^4}-\frac1{5!n^5}\right)+\cdots+\left(\frac1{(4+2k)!n^{4+2k}} -\frac1{(4+2k+1)!n^{4+2k+1}}\right)>0 $$

and

$$ \left(\frac1{4! n^4}-\frac1{5!n^5}\right)+\cdots+\left(\frac1{(4+2k)!n^{4+k}} -\frac1{(4+2k+1)!n^{4+2k}}\right) +\frac1{(4+2k+2)!n^{4+2k+2}} >0 $$

then,

$$\sum_{k\geq4}\frac{(-1)^k}{k!n^k}>0$$

we have (or the **lemma** below)

$$e^{-\frac1n}=1-\frac1n+\frac1{2n^2}-\frac1{6n^3}+\sum_{k\geq4}\frac{(-1)^k}{k!n^k}\gt 1-\frac1n+\frac1{2n^2}-\frac1{6n^3}$$

it is obvious that

$$e^{\frac1{1+n}}\gt 1+\frac1{1+n}+\frac1{2{(1+n)^2}}+\frac1{6{(1+n)^3}}+ \frac1{24{(1+n)^4}}$$

if $n>2$, it is easy to check that

$$e^{-\frac1n}+e^{\frac1{1+n}}\gt 2-\frac1n+\frac1{2n^2}-\frac1{6n^3}+\frac1{1+n}+\frac1{2{(1+n)^2}}+\frac1{6{(1+n)^3}}+ \frac1{24{(1+n)^4}}\\ >2$$

In fact

$$n^3(n+1)^3\left(-\frac1n+\frac1{2n^2}-\frac1{6n^3}+\frac1{1+n}+\frac1{2{(1+n)^2}}+\frac1{6{(1+n)^3}}+ \frac1{24{(1+n)^4}}\right)=\frac{n^3}{24(n+1)}-\frac16=\frac{n(n^2-4)-4}{24(n+1)}\gt0$$

> edit: 
>
> Lemma 
>
> $x\ne0$, $k$ is a odd number, then
>
> $$e^x\gt 1+x+\frac{x^2}{2!}+\dotsb+ \frac{x^k}{k!}$$
>
> Proof  $\qquad$ according to Taylor formula, there exists $\theta(0\lt\theta\lt1)$ such that
>
> $$e^x= 1+x+\frac{x^2}{2!}+\dotsb+ \frac{x^k}{k!}+\frac{e^{\theta x}}{(k+1)!}x^{k+1}$$

Comment: Probably true but not obvious.

Comment: @nayrb Is it obvious now?

Comment: I definitely wouldn't call it obvious.  Why should $2+(\frac1{n+1}-\frac1n)+O(n^2)$ necessarily be positive?  You probably *can* collapse terms in your last expression to show manifest positivity, but it's certainly not immediately obvious.

Comment: @2016 Exactly - that's a negative quantity.  Your expression is $2-\frac1{n(n+1)}+\frac1{2n^2}+\frac1{2(n+1)^2}+\ldots$; it's certainly not immediately clear (to me) that that's $\gt 2$.  What's your argument for it?  (You have two positive terms of size approximately $\frac12 n^{-2}$ and one negative term of size approximately $n^{-2}$, so to $O(n^2)$ the expression actually cancels.)

Comment: (Actually, I'll answer my own question: we have $\frac1{2n^2}+\frac1{2(n+1)^2}\geq\frac1{n(n+1)}$ by the AGM applied to $\frac1{n^2}$ and $\frac1{(n+1)^2}$.  It's very likely that you can use a similar argument for the $O(n^{-3})$ terms and get an $AGM$ result that offers manifest positivity to $O(n^{-4})$, but it's by no means trivial)

Comment: @2016 If I'm reading Alpha correctly, you have your final expression exactly _backwards_ in sign and the value of your expression is in fact small-negative for large $n$.  (Which is okay, as on second glance you're subtracting it from $2$ - but it _is_ a subtle sign flip, and I still wouldn't say that any of this is trivial.)  [Check this?](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%281%2Fn%29-%281%2F%282n^2%29%29%2B%281%2F%286n^3%29%29-%281%2F%281%2Bn%29%29-%281%2F%282%281%2Bn%29^2%29%29-%281%2F%286%28n%2B1%29^3%29%29-%281%2F%2824%28n%2B1%29^4%29%29)