# What $\alpha$ such that if $xy=\alpha$, then $e^{-x}+e^{-y}\geq 2e^{-\sqrt \alpha} $?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, inequality, exponential-function

For every $ x,y \gt 0$, if $ xy=\alpha$, then we have

$$e^{-x}+e^{-y}\geq 2e^{-\sqrt \alpha} $$

What are the possible values of   $\alpha$?

---

[$2 < e^{1/(n+1)} + e^{-1/n}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/805999/show-that-2-e1-n1-e-1-n) led to  this problem. so, $\alpha=1$  is allowed.

The problem is difficult, if not very:  $e^{-x}+e^{-\frac1x}\geq 2e^{-1}$ is not easy to prove.

**P.S.:**
1)  $\quad e^{-\sqrt \alpha}\geq e^{\dfrac{-x-y}2}$

2) $\quad e^{-x}+e^{-y}\geq 2e^{-\sqrt {xy}} $ does not hold for all $x,y\gt0$! Just think $x=1,y\to0$

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: If $x,y\gt0$, then $\alpha=xy\gt0$.

Comment: Holds iff $\alpha \ge 1$ I think.

Comment: @Macavity me too. The problem is: proof ie not easy

Comment: Finding an elementary proof may not be easy.  Essentially you are seeking the subset of positive reals where $f(x) = e^{-x}$ is GA-convex.  This would be where $xf''(x)+f'(x) \ge 0$, which translates to $e^{-x}(x-1)\ge 0$ or $x\ge 1 \implies \alpha \ge 1$.

Answer (score 2):

The argument in my [answer to the linked question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/806951/21467) extends with minor modifications to the case $\alpha\ge 1$; thus if $\alpha\ge 1$ then the global minimum of $e^{-x}+e^{-y}$ on $xy=\alpha$ is also the only critical point, and occurs at $x=y=\sqrt\alpha$, so the minimum is indeed $2e^{-\sqrt\alpha}$.

On the other hand, if $0 < \alpha < 1$, then for $f(x)=e^{-x}+e^{-\alpha/x}$ we have, by direct computation,
$$ f'(\sqrt\alpha) = 0
\qquad\text{and}\qquad
f''(\sqrt\alpha) = 2\Big(1-\frac1{\sqrt\alpha}\Big) e^{-\sqrt\alpha} < 0 $$
Since $f''$ is continuous, this shows that the value of $f$ at $\sqrt\alpha$ is a strict local maximum.  In particular, there are $x$ near $\sqrt\alpha$ such that $f(x)<f(\sqrt\alpha)=2e^{-\sqrt\alpha}$, so the inequality does not hold when $0<\alpha<1$.

Comment: Let me know if you'd like me to demonstrate the so-called "minor modifications".